# Python all combinations of data

Tags: python, list, combinations

So I have a file  structure like this *(data on each line)*:

```
A
B
C
...
```

I want to read each line of this file and combine those into all possible combinations, the result I'm looking for would be this *(which I would put in a list)*:

```
A
AB
AC
ABC
ACB
B
BA
BC
BCA
BAC
C
CA
CB
CBA
CAB
```

Obviously I'd be looking to deal with more than just those three lines...

thanks

Comment: What you are looking for, sir, is [`itertools.permutations`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations).

Answer (score 5):

You should use the `itertools` library. You want to generate all unique permutations of each element in the powerset. Some code might look like

```
from itertools import permutations, combinations, chain

# Taken from itertools page, but edited slightly to not return empty set
def powerset(iterable):
    "powerset([1,2,3]) --> (1,) (2,) (3,) (1,2) (1,3) (2,3) (1,2,3)"
    s = list(iterable)
    return chain.from_iterable(combinations(s, r) for r in range(1, len(s)+1))
```

Then

```
In [1]: s = ('A', 'B', 'C')

In [2]: [j for i in powerset(s) for j in permutations(i)]
Out[2]: 
[('A',),
 ('B',),
 ('C',),
 ('A', 'B'),
 ('B', 'A'),
 ('A', 'C'),
 ('C', 'A'),
 ('B', 'C'),
 ('C', 'B'),
 ('A', 'B', 'C'),
 ('A', 'C', 'B'),
 ('B', 'A', 'C'),
 ('B', 'C', 'A'),
 ('C', 'A', 'B'),
 ('C', 'B', 'A')]
```